# WebApi2 how to pass Json with an array

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have the following Json with array that I am sending it from `AngularJS`

```
{id_fleet: 4177, id_fleetfeature: Array[2]}

var dataFeatures = {
    id_fleet: $scope.id,
    id_fleetfeature: $scope.selectedFeatures
}
$http.put(myUrl + "Fleets/Insert", JSON.stringify(dataFeatures)).then(function () {
    Materialize.toast('Features insertadas correctamente', 3000);
    $scope.refreshData();
});
```

**Web API Model**

```
public class modelFleetFeatures {
    public int id_fleet { get; set; }
    public int[] id_fleetfeature { get; set; }
}
```

**Web API Function**

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("api/Fleets/FleetFeature/Update")]
public HttpResponseMessage updateFleetFeature(List<modelFleetFeatures> data)
{
    var cnt = 0;

    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        db.sp_Fleet_FleetFeaturesDelete(item.id_fleet);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        db.sp_Fleet_FleetFeaturesInsert(item.id_fleet, item.id_fleetfeature[cnt]);
        db.SaveChanges();
        cnt +=1;
    }

    return new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
}
```

In the `Web API` the value of data always gets null

Comment: Instead of passing a list of objects as a parameter, create another class that contains a list of modelFleetFeatures as a property.. this way you are only accepting a single valid object as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

You are sending single object in JSON, so why expecting list of object in API action?
Just expect single object in api Action , you will get that object model in call like :

```
public HttpResponseMessage updateFleetFeature(modelFleetFeatures data)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

And no need to stringify json object in put request.

```
$http.put(myUrl + "Fleets/Insert", dataFeatures).then(function () {
    Materialize.toast('Features insertadas correctamente', 3000);
    $scope.refreshData();
});
```